# Git move pull request from one repository to another repository

Tags: git

I have a repository `ONE` with some work in it. There is a open pull request called `pull-request` which I would like to move **with all commits** into another repository called `TWO`.

```
Repository "ONE" c1_c2_c3_c4_c10_c11_c12_c13...
                            \
     branch "pull-request"   \_c5_c6_c7_c8_c9



Repository "TWO" _____________________________
                                              \
     branch "pull-request-from-repository-ONE" \_c5_c6_c7_c8_c9
```

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Steve Bennetts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718170/2008111) and [CodeWizards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718185/2008111) answers I could get it to work with a mix of both answers like this:

in Repository TWO

```
git remote add ONE  https://...
git fetch ONE pull-request

git checkout -b pull-request-from-repository-ONE
git cherry-pick [sha-commit-hash]
```

note I messed up with trying to cherry-pick a range
of commits, cause my pull-request branch had merges already inside...
so anyway, cherry-picking single commits seems to work

Comment: what exactly `[sha-commit-hash]` is refering to here? Is it the commit at the tip of the PR on repo ONE?

Comment: @stdout sorry (8 months too lates) `[sha-commit-hash]` as mentioned in the answer I was cherry-picking single commits. So after the first two steps in the response I was able to cherry-pick single commits from the branch `pull-request` into the branch `pull-request-from-repository-ONE`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this "pull request" is on a service like Github, you just treat it like any other branch, on your computer:

```
git remote add repoone https://....
git fetch repoone
git merge pull-request
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. I see with this solution I can do the trick but now I have the entire Repository One in Repository Two, which is not really what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the diagram - I had assumed that Repo Two was a fork of Repo One. I tend to go with cherry picking single commits as you did, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but in a workaround:

Add the 2 remotes to your repository. then do a `git cherry-pick` of the desired commit to the second repository and now create a new pull request as usual.

The point is that in GIT you can have multiple remotes and the commits can be "added" to any of the branches.

If you work with github the pull request are fetched locally to your repository so you can merge them right away.

---

#### GitHub Checkout github pull requests locally

https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247